# NoHostAvailableException while bulk loading data into Cassandra

Tags: cassandra-2.0

I'm trying to load 1 Million LUBM dataset into Cassandra. But, I keep getting this Exception after about 200,000 inserts.

> Exception in thread "main" com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: localhost/127.0.0.1 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.DriverException: Timeout during read))

The server is still alive. I can still execute CQL queries using Datastax Dev Center. Prior to this, I was getting WriteTimeoutException and hence I tweaked some options in .yaml

Here are the specs of my system:

CPU- Intel I5 - 2 cores| 
Memory- 4GB |
Hard Disk- 500 GB 4 Drives.

I have an OWL file from which the data is read and is inserted into Cassandra. I have mixed workloads. Sometimes, based upon a condition,  I need to retrieve the data from the row and append the new data to it and write it to the same row.  This mustn't be the cause for this problem because this condition must have occurred plenty of times during the 200k inserts.

I'm using an external hard disk for storing commitlogs. 
concurrent_reads is set to 16.
concurrent_writes is set to 32. 
read_timeout has been set to 10000 and so as write_timeout. 
MAX_HEAP_SIZE="2G"
HEAP_NEWSIZE="200M"

As soon as I get hat exception, I see this log with this pattern

```
    INFO [MemoryMeter:1] 2014-03-25 16:28:56,498 Memtable.java (line 449) CFS(Keyspace='rdf', ColumnFamily='lubm1m.lubm1m_teacherof_idx') liveRatio is 15.733535462912831 (just-counted was 15.733535462912831).  calculation took 91ms for 665 cells
 INFO [MemoryMeter:1] 2014-03-25 16:30:01,560 Memtable.java (line 449) CFS(Keyspace='system', ColumnFamily='sstable_activity') liveRatio is 15.896188158961882 (just-counted was 15.896188158961882).  calculation took 37ms for 411 cells
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-03-25 16:33:22,252 GCInspector.java (line 116) GC for ParNew: 15581 ms for 1 collections, 395151608 used; max is 1038876672
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-03-25 16:33:24,894 StatusLogger.java (line 55) Pool Name                    Active   Pending      Completed   Blocked  All Time Blocked
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-03-25 16:33:26,956 StatusLogger.java (line 70) ReadStage                         0         0         343094         0                 0
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-03-25 16:33:26,957 StatusLogger.java (line 70) RequestResponseStage              0         0              1         0                 0
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-03-25 16:33:26,996 StatusLogger.java (line 70) ReadRepairStage                   0         0              0         0                 0
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-03-25 16:33:27,004 StatusLogger.java (line 70) MutationStage                     0         0         601747         0                 0
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-03-25 16:33:27,024 StatusLogger.java (line 70) ReplicateOnWriteStage             0         0              0         0                 0
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-03-25 16:33:27,031 StatusLogger.java (line 70) GossipStage                       0         0              0         0                 0
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-03-25 16:33:27,066 StatusLogger.java (line 70) AntiEntropyStage                  0         0              0         0                 0
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-03-25 16:33:27,067 StatusLogger.java (line 70) MigrationStage                    0         0              0         0                 0
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-03-25 16:33:27,098 StatusLogger.java (line 70) MemtablePostFlusher               0         0             52         0                 0
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-03-25 16:33:27,099 StatusLogger.java (line 70) MemoryMeter                       0         0            139         0                 0
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-03-25 16:33:27,100 StatusLogger.java (line 70) FlushWriter                       0         0             31         0                16
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-03-25 16:33:27,101 StatusLogger.java (line 70) MiscStage                         0         0              0         0                 0
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-03-25 16:33:27,130 StatusLogger.java (line 70) PendingRangeCalculator            0         0              1         0                 0
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-03-25 16:33:27,133 StatusLogger.java (line 70) commitlog_archiver                0         0              0         0                 0
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-03-25 16:33:27,134 StatusLogger.java (line 70) InternalResponseStage             0         0              0         0                 0
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-03-25 16:33:27,142 StatusLogger.java (line 70) HintedHandoff                     0         0              0         0                 0
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-03-25 16:33:27,223 StatusLogger.java (line 79) CompactionManager                 0         0
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-03-25 16:33:27,232 StatusLogger.java (line 81) Commitlog                       n/a         0
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-03-25 16:33:27,262 StatusLogger.java (line 93) MessagingService                n/a       0/0
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-03-25 16:33:27,262 StatusLogger.java (line 103) Cache Type                     Size                 Capacity               KeysToSave
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-03-25 16:33:27,287 StatusLogger.java (line 105) KeyCache                      17212                 51380224                      all
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-03-25 16:33:27,335 StatusLogger.java (line 111) RowCache                          0                        0                      all
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-03-25 16:33:27,336 StatusLogger.java (line 118) ColumnFamily                Memtable ops,data
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-03-25 16:33:27,336 StatusLogger.java (line 121) system.schema_triggers                    0,0
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-03-25 16:33:27,337 StatusLogger.java (line 121) system.local                              0,0
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-03-25 16:33:27,337 StatusLogger.java (line 121) system.peers                              0,0
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-03-25 16:33:27,338 StatusLogger.java (line 121) system.batchlog                           0,0
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-03-25 16:33:27,338 StatusLogger.java (line 121) system.NodeIdInfo                         0,0
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-03-25 16:33:27,339 StatusLogger.java (line 121) system.compactions_in_progress                 0,0
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-03-25 16:33:27,339 StatusLogger.java (line 121) system.schema_keyspaces                4,1130
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-03-25 16:33:27,340 StatusLogger.java (line 121) system.compaction_history            38,11220
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-03-25 16:33:27,340 StatusLogger.java (line 121) system.paxos                              0,0
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-03-25 16:33:27,340 StatusLogger.java (line 121) system.schema_columns             3361,891818
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-03-25 16:33:27,341 StatusLogger.java (line 121) system.schema_columnfamilies         1426,394018
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-03-25 16:33:27,341 StatusLogger.java (line 121) system.IndexInfo                          0,0
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-03-25 16:33:27,342 StatusLogger.java (line 121) system.range_xfers                        0,0
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-03-25 16:33:27,344 StatusLogger.java (line 121) system.peer_events                        0,0
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-03-25 16:33:27,344 StatusLogger.java (line 121) system.hints                              0,0
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-03-25 16:33:27,345 StatusLogger.java (line 121) system.sstable_activity           1542,196000
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-03-25 16:33:27,345 StatusLogger.java (line 121) KeyspaceCumulus.POS_RN_NUM                 0,0
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-03-25 16:33:27,346 StatusLogger.java (line 121) KeyspaceCumulus.DICT_SO_REVERSE                 0,0
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-03-25 16:33:27,346 StatusLogger.java (line 121) KeyspaceCumulus.SPO_RN_DT                 0,0
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-03-25 16:33:27,347 StatusLogger.java (line 121) KeyspaceCumulus.DICT_P_REVERSE                 0,0
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-03-25 16:33:27,347 StatusLogger.java (line 121) KeyspaceCumulus.SPOC                      0,0
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-03-25 16:33:27,348 StatusLogger.java (line 121) KeyspaceCumulus.POSC                      0,0
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-03-25 16:33:27,348 StatusLogger.java (line 121) KeyspaceCumulus.counter                   0,0
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-03-25 16:33:27,349 StatusLogger.java (line 121) KeyspaceCumulus.SCHEMA_O_PROPS                 0,0
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-03-25 16:33:27,350 StatusLogger.java (line 121) KeyspaceCumulus.SCHEMA_D_PROPS                 0,0
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-03-25 16:33:27,350 StatusLogger.java (line 121) KeyspaceCumulus.PREFIX_TO_NS                 0,0
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-03-25 16:33:27,352 StatusLogger.java (line 121) KeyspaceCumulus.POS_RN_DT                 0,0
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-03-25 16:33:27,352 StatusLogger.java (line 121) KeyspaceCumulus.SPO_RN_NUM                 0,0
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-03-25 16:33:27,353 StatusLogger.java (line 121) KeyspaceCumulus.SCHEMA_CLASSES                 0,0
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-03-25 16:33:27,353 StatusLogger.java (line 121) KeyspaceCumulus.OSPC                      0,0
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-03-25 16:33:27,354 StatusLogger.java (line 121) KeyspaceCumulus.DICT_SO                   0,0
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-03-25 16:33:27,354 StatusLogger.java (line 121) KeyspaceCumulus.DICT_P                    0,0
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-03-25 16:33:27,355 StatusLogger.java (line 121) rdf.animal                                0,0
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-03-25 16:33:27,355 StatusLogger.java (line 121) rdf.lubm20                                0,0
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-03-25 16:33:27,356 StatusLogger.java (line 121) rdf.bsbm50                                0,0
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-03-25 16:33:27,356 StatusLogger.java (line 121) rdf.tim                                   0,0
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-03-25 16:33:27,357 StatusLogger.java (line 121) rdf.bsbm250                               0,0
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-03-25 16:33:27,357 StatusLogger.java (line 121) rdf.lubm1m                    152700,22140112
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-03-25 16:33:27,358 StatusLogger.java (line 121) rdf.lubm3                                 0,0
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-03-25 16:33:27,358 StatusLogger.java (line 121) system_traces.sessions                    0,0
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2014-03-25 16:33:27,359 StatusLogger.java (line 121) system_traces.events                      0,0
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

increase socket timeout with SocketOptions. You may try to configure it on datastax client and server side as well. Also, see if reducing consistency could be any help?

-Vivek

Comment: Thanks. I got it solved. I followed this: http://www.opensourceconnections.com/2013/08/31/building-the-perfect-cassandra-test-environment/

And I increased concurrent_reads to 64(HW specific). No more crashes and WriteTimeoutExceptions.